# SQL: first show future records, then the rest. Both by create_date DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have table like:

```
id  | create_date | start_date | status
112 | 2015-03-13  | 2015-03-14 |   1
106 | 2015-03-07  | 2015-03-19 |   2
105 | 2015-03-06  | 2015-03-29 |   1
104 | 2015-03-05  | 2015-03-29 |   1
101 | 2015-03-03  | 2015-03-20 |   1
100 | 2015-03-01  | 2015-03-03 |   1
 99 | 2015-03-01  | 2015-03-06 |   2
```

Now, I want to select and order these records by:

1. records with `status = 1` and `start_date >= NOW()` has to be first, ordered by `create_date DESC` - the newest record with `status = 1 and start_date >= now()` will be first. These are 'active'
2. other records (it means records with `status = 0`, `status = 2` and `status = 1 AND start_date < NOW()`) will be behind active, sort by `create_date DESC`.

Expected output:

```
id  | create_date | start_date | status
112 | 2015-03-13  | 2015-03-14 |   1
105 | 2015-03-06  | 2015-03-29 |   1
104 | 2015-03-05  | 2015-03-29 |   1
101 | 2015-03-03  | 2015-03-20 |   1
106 | 2015-03-07  | 2015-03-19 |   2
100 | 2015-03-01  | 2015-03-03 |   1
 99 | 2015-03-01  | 2015-03-06 |   2 -- behind id 100 not because of higher status, but because of create_date (I store datetime instead of date).
```

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT a.[columns],
       d.[columns],
       r1.[columns],
       r2.[columns]
FROM articles a
JOIN reg r1
    ON r1.id = a.locality_id
LEFT JOIN reg r2
    ON r2.id = r1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN `d` AS d
    ON d.id = a.demander_id
WHERE a.s_id = 1
ORDER BY (a.status = 1 AND a.start_date >= NOW()) DESC,
         a.create_date DESC
```

Current output:

```
id  | create_date | start_date | status
105 | 2015-03-06  | 2015-03-29 |   1
104 | 2015-03-05  | 2015-03-29 |   1
101 | 2015-03-03  | 2015-03-20 |   1
112 | 2015-03-13  | 2015-03-14 |   1
106 | 2015-03-07  | 2015-03-19 |   2
100 | 2015-03-01  | 2015-03-03 |   1
 99 | 2015-03-01  | 2015-03-06 |   2
```

It returns me future records with `status = 1` before the other, it's okay, but ordered by `start_date DESC`.

This `DESC` should mean 'order by a condition before which returns 1 or 0 desc (first records when condition is true, than the rest) and then order records by create date from newest'. But it do something else.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but you need to compare with `CURRENT_DATE()` instead of `NOW()`:

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN status = 1 AND start_date >= CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1
    ELSE                                                  2
END, create_date DESC
```

If current datetime is `2015-03-14 00:00:01` then:

- `2015-03-14 >= NOW()` does not match
- `2015-03-14 >= CURRENT_DATE()` match

Comment: Thanks a lot! With `NOW` it's the same, `current_date` returns exactly what I need.